# Dynamic data in jmeter request

Tags: dynamic, time, jmeter, stamp

I am using jmeter and i need help how to Deal with this dynamic data (nid:sub-1554578997748-161 ) to i can send it successfully in the request
i found that first part (1554578997748) is the time stamp in milliseconds 
but what is 161 and how to manipulate with it

This is the request:

POST data:

```
["SUBSCRIBE\nreceipt:subscribe-900169ec-b218-4f3c-aa9e-35e7d599b3b3\nid:sub-1554578997748-161\ndestination:/topic/session.900169ec-b218-4f3c-aa9e-35e7d599b3b3"]
```

Cookie Data:

```
amelia_s=YzJWemMybHZiaTFqYjI5cmFXVXVkakU2UWtwMmFqaEhZbk5FVkd0ME9YVkZTanBEVWxkVU0zSmpWR1poVWtab1VIVkZObFJUY2tOc2RIVmhUVmw2U0haV1ZqUkpVR28xYVRaM1ZXRlVkRkE1ZEd4M1NFTmpZblF2VFU5d2J6SkhTRTF3UVZoMlEzbG5QVDA=
```

Comment: What is your objective? Please tell us more what you really trying to do. Manipulating is a broad term.

Comment: i found that this data (nid:sub-1554578997748-161) is changing every time in the script. and i need help how to send it successfully to the server